# "Podman machine start" : All pipe instances are busy

Tags: podman, podman-compose

I am trying to set up Podman in my Windows 10 system, but I stuck with an error "All pipe instances are busy”, please help me how can I resolve this or let me know if I am doing anything wrong here.

Step 1:-  Podman machine init  (This command works)
Step 2:-  Podman machine start (Getting Error:  All pipe instances are busy)

Please find the attached screenshots.

[image: Winget]

[image: podman version]

[image: Podman machine start error: All pipe instances are busy]

Comment: I searched for _"All pipe instances are busy"_ in [Github Podman repo discussions](https://github.com/containers/podman/discussions?discussions_q=%22all+pipe+instances+are+busy%22+) and [GitHub Podman repo issues](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+%22all+pipe+instances+are+busy%22+) without finding anything. Maybe you've discovered a new bug?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to Docker, but rather a competing project.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem which was resolved by removing %USERPROFILE%/.wslconfig, see https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/15176